# Automation script is not working?

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, ui-automation

This is the first time I get my hands on with automation instruments in xcode The script works well for all button taps but the one making server connection. I don't know the reason

Here is the script I tried so far

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.pushTimeout(4);
target.popTimeout();

var window=target.frontMostApp().mainWindow()
var appScroll=window.scrollViews()[0];
appScroll.logElementTree();
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);
appScroll.buttons()[1].tap();
```

The above script works up to showing the UIActivityIndicator instead of moving to next controller after success

I know There must be a very simple point I am missing. So help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAutomation attempts to make things "easy" for the developer, but in doing so it can make things very confusing.  It sounds like you're getting a reference to `window`, waiting for a button to appear, then executing `.tap()` on that button.

I see that you've already considered messing with `target.pushTimeout()`, which is related to your issue. The timeout system lets you do something that would be impossible in any sane system: get a reference to an element *before it exists*.  I suspect that behind-the-scenes, UIAutomation repeatedly attempts to get the reference you want -- as long as the `timeout` will allow.

So, in the example you've posted, it's possible for this "feature" to actually hurt you.

```
var window=target.frontMostApp().mainWindow()
var appScroll=window.scrollViews()[0];
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);
appScroll.buttons()[1].tap();
```

What if the view changes during the 2-second delay?  Your reference to `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow.scrollViews()[0]` may be invalid, or it may not point to the object you think you're pointing at.

We got around this in our [Illuminator framework](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator) by forgetting about the timeout system altogether, and just manually re-evaluating a given reference until it actually returns something.  We called it [`waitForChildExistence`](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/gem/resources/js/Extensions.js#L1283), but the functionality is basically as follows:

```
var myTimeout = 3;  // how long we want to wait

// this function selects an element 
// relative to a parent element (target) that we will pass in
var selectorFn = function (myTarget) {
    var ret = myTarget.frontMostApp().mainWindow.scrollViews()[0];
    // assert that ret exists, is visible, etc
    return ret;
}

// re-evaluate our selector until we get something
var element = null;
var later = get_current_time() + myTimeout;
while (element === null && get_current_time() < later) {
    try {
        element = selectorFn(target);
    } catch (e) {
        // must not have worked
    }
}

// check whether element is still null

// do something with element
```

For cases where there is a temporary progress dialog, this code will simply wait for it to disappear before successfully returning the element you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer I will reply after trying it out

Comment: You have predicted right pushTimeout seems to be the problem in my case